# Fiber-optic transceiver ICs for applications other than fiber-optic Ethernet?

Tags: communication, ethernet, data, optics, optical-fibre

When we talk about fiber-optic transmission, we almost always talk about copper to fiber-optic **Ethernet** conversion using fiber-optic transceivers.

But since fiber-optic communication is just transmission of any electrical signal in the form of light, I was wondering if there are other transceivers available for fiber-optic transmission, I mean for interfaces/protocols other than Ethernet.

In my search I could not come across any such transceivers. Whenever and wherever I see the word fiber-optic, it is related to Ethernet/networking only.

Any comments are appreciated.

Comment: Have you like, googled, or read the fiber optic communcation wikipedia list which lists a bunch of different fiber optic standards?

Comment: I did, but what I am mainly looking for is non-Ethernet fiber-optic "transceivers". I will try to look them up again, but if you a link or name of such a transceiver handy, I had appreciate if you could please share it.

Comment: 'we almost always talk about copper to fiber-optic Ethernet conversion using fiber-optic transceivers.' I think the people working on backbone infrastructure have a thing or two to say about that claim. The reason you can't find any transceivers is because ethernet is the dominant infrastructure used for LAN. Other applications tend to either not be for computer networking (S/P DIF, Thunderbolt) or just not the kind of thing a consumer can buy (because they are meant for specific applications).

Comment: If this is not a shopping question (off-topic) then it's unclear what you're really asking. Fiber-optic transceiver devices for 'low-level' use in any suitable communication link exist, so it's likely that you're looking in the wrong places and/or for the wrong things.

Comment: @JorenVaes Thanks for the comments. That was close to the answer I am looking for. So, basically there are no transceiver chips or components available (like fiber-optic Ethernet transceivers from Broadcom, etc.) which can be used to convert some other signals (e.g. USB) to fiber-optic? I am asking from a PCB level implementation point of view.

Comment: @brhans This is not a shopping question and I am definitely asking this question in the correct place. Could you please site an example of the transceiver devices you are talking about?

Comment: you can not just simply convert any signal to fiber signal. in osi terms, you are trying to convert usb to fiber on osi layer 1 but in reality it needs to be done on osi layer 2, just like ata vs sata, pci vs pcie. "fiberizing" usb is 100% possible, just like wireless usb, but has very little market value.

Comment: @user3528438 Thanks for the comment. Just to clarify your point regarding OSI layer - we cannot simply convert these (Ethernet/USB/etc.) signals to fiber-optic on physical layer and convert it back in its intended form, right? So basically, we cannot simply do this conversion at discrete level and we would need a transceiver that operates at layer 2 to do this conversion? But again, due to very little market value and applications, such transceiver chips/ICs are not available. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: 2105 hits [here](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/optoelectronics/fiber-optics-transceiver-modules/118)

Comment: Surprisingly, came across this: https://www.silicon-line.com/vcsel-driver-tia-detail/sl86050.html

Comment: Most transceivers are protocol transparent and will transmit and receive whatever you send to them, so you are free to implement whatever protocol you want.

Comment: @LoveEnigma, that's a chip that a transceiver company might use to make a transceiver module, not a transceiver module itself.

Comment: AFAIK, SFP transceivers aren't limited to Ethernet, since they don't actually interpret the data flowing through them in any way. (Very similar transceivers are used for Fibre Channel and Infiniband for example - I'm not sure if Ethernet, FC and IB ones are directly compatible, but if not it's probably just because the switch detects that it's the wrong transceiver, not because it can't work)

Comment: Since you're talking about ICs, I bet that almost all of the ICs you find are not limited to Ethernet.

Comment: @winny If that was the case, why are there transceivers available specifically for Ethernet? If I ignore the protocol for a moment, at least the pin-out of such transceivers is specifically to connect Etherney PHY output signals. What would be needed if, for example, I have HDMI signals in their standard format and would want to convert them and transmit over fiber-optic cable? I would need some transceiver (which probably is not available for HDMI) or need to implement it using a processor which would take HDMI signals and then transmit it over Ethernet MAC broadly speaking. Right?

Comment: @ThePhoton Yes, I do understand that. What I was trying to point out is that at least for USB to fiber-optic, we have that chip as a transceiver. I am wondering how products like Thunderbolt/HDMI to fiber-optic converters would be working...

Comment: @immibis But SFP transceivers have Ethernet specific pin-out right? How can connected any other interface to it (like USB, Ethernet, etc.)?

Comment: They are of course advertised for use with Ethernet because that’s the popular end use for them. You would need to translate the several electrical signals into your own protocol, send it over fiber and translate back into HDMI in the other end. Pinout is irrelevant and they are not Ethernet specific. It’s a question much too broad for this site how to send HDMI data over fiber.

Comment: @LoveEnigma No, they do not have an Ethernet-specific pinout, they have an SFP-specific pinout.

Comment: @immibis Yes, you are correct. By asking this question here I might have seemed a bit dumb, but at least I got my doubt cleared that fiber-optic transceivers are not only for Ethernet purpose. However, transferring other signals (USB, HDMI, etc.) would be more difficult as they would need to consolidated/serialized (with appropriate logic levels) such that there is one TX pair and one RX pair that goes to the fiber-optic transceiver.

Answer (score 3):

SONET is kind of popular in the telecomms world, very different to ethernet, and kind of cool in its way.

In reality many non ethernet uses exist, but we tend to try to use rates that are close enough to something used by either the phone company or the datacenter because economies of scale make optical modules for those line rates all kinds of cheap.

MADI for example (multichannel digital audio used in pro environments) often goes over 155Mb/s SFP modules marketed for SONET use by the telecom crowd, IIRC it actually runs the line at 125Mb/s, but close enough.

SDI digital video is another example, either at 1.55Gb/s, 3Gb/s or 12Gb/s, again SFP modules that are close enough usually exist.

Particularly with SFP interfaces they usually don't care about the protocol as long as DC balance is not too horrible and whatever you are sending can survive being highpassed at a few MHz (The ALC will stuff up the levels at the the slicer if you go slower then that). Apart from that, generate a PECL version of whatever you like and stuff it into a SFP+ socket, odds are it will work if you pick a reasonable module for the speed you need.

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned there are many possible communication transport layers possible over fiber optic links. Here is one useful application that uses a fiber optic link to extend a USB interface out to far beyond what is possible with standard USB cabling.

[image]

<sup>[(Source Vendor Page)](https://sewelldirect.com/link-link-usb-50ft?stm_type=ppc&stm_source=adwords&stm_brand=unnasigned&campaignid=1063104648&adgroupid=54729752360&creative=257725846002&targetid:pla-293946777986&feeditemid=&keyword=&matchtype=&gclid=Cj0KCQjwk_TbBRDsARIsAALJSOYfu18BmPhWB1jaJy3ZfOW05N-elxXpULDW4Hkff2OKeY8ZM_UKuxAaAkZqEALw_wcB)</sup>

This example shows a USB3.0 link of 50 feet but there are many product options in this space. If you search you can find USB2, HDMI, Ethernet, Audio etc.

Answer (score 1):

There are many other link-layers transported on Fiber-optic medium, apart from Ethernet.

How about [S/P DIF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S/PDIF), [Fiber Channel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibre_Channel), [Thunderbolt optical cables](https://www.corning.com/optical-cables-by-corning/worldwide/en/products/thunderbolt-optical-cables.html), to name a few ?

Comment: 1. "Fibre Channel" is spelled with the British spelling of *Fibre*. 2. Many Fibre Channel rates are very close to Ethernet rates, and use similar encoding, so the transceivers for one will typically work for the other (but might be sold under different PNs due to test plan, etc)

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised no one mentioned good ol' TOSLINK. The simple board-mounted transmitters and receivers for it are available from digikey and the cables are cheap.

TOSLINK technology has evolved over the years. There are [general purpose devices](https://www.tme.eu/en/Document/d5bc7a8e7a158c6bf81355ccceb0b4a5/TOFC100-xx.pdf) for up to 8Mbps and full-duplex SMI transceivers.